# "No Metadata Classes to process" when trying to create the schema in sf2

Tags: symfony

after doing php app/console doctrine:schema:create I'm getting the
message "No Metadata Classes to process.".

My steps are just these:

Download sf2, create the bundle Jander/ClarBlundle and create Jander/ClarBundle/Resources/config/doctrine/Jander.ClarBundle.Entity.User.orm.dcm.yml
    with this content:

```
Jander\ClarBundle\Entity\User:
type: entity
table: user
id:
    id:
        type: integer
        generator:
            strategy: AUTO
fields:
    name:
        type: string
        length: 255
```

I don't have any problems with doctrine:database:create.

Any idea?

sf2 beta1.

Javier

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the path to your YAML file. In Symfony2 beta2 (due soon), there will be a few changes made to ease use of convention, but in beta1, your entity YAML file must be in the path:

`Jander/ClarBundle/Resources/config/doctrine/metadata/orm/Jander.ClarBundle.Entity.User.dcm.yml`

Note the `metadata/orm/` in the file path and the `.dcm.yml` extension instead of `.orm.yml`.

That is to say, your current setup should work after beta2 is rolled out, but for now, you still have to use longhand.

Reference from the Symfony2 blog [here](http://symfony.com/blog/symfony2-getting-easier-part-3).

Answer (score 2):

Try to clear cache:

```
php app/console cache:clear
```

Comment: clearing the cache worked for me because the entity that I generated wasn't valid (had spaces in the field names) (oops)

Answer (score 0):

This problem comes when you have something wrong in your YML / XML / Entity files. 
Possible reason paths or names are wrong.